# In Takenoko does the player have to choose both their actions before performing either

Tags: takenoko

In the rules it states:

> To finalize their choices, the player puts two chips on the appropriate spaces of their individual Board.
>
> The order in which the actions are resolved is chosen by the player.

Does the player have to choose their two actions at the start of the 2nd step and then action them.  Or can they perform one action, see the consequences and then decide what action to take as their second action?

We've been playing the latter, but I'm not sure if the former is intended by a strict reading of the rules.

I.e. are the tokens just to keep track of what you've done so you don't accidentally perform the same action twice, or are they intended to lock your actions in before you perform any of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actions are chosen and resolved sequentially as you have been playing, so you can see the result of your first action before choosing and resolving your second action.

While the original rules do seem to indicate that your two actions must be chosen before you resolve anything, it was clarified in [the official FAQ](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54da1198e4b0e9d26e55b0fc/t/550c469de4b07e28b670552b/1426867869749/takenoko_faq_eng.pdf):

> The two actions are chosen sequentially. This means that if a player choses to draw a new objective card, he can look at it before deciding what his second action will be.

Note that most of the official links to the FAQ now seem to be dead, so I assume that since the FAQ was released in 2012 these changes may be included in newer editions of the game.